# How to speedup raspi boot when eth0 not connected?

Tags: boot, dhcp

I've got my raspi configured for DHCP on eth0 and wlan0. When eth0 is disconnected (which is the default), start time is very slow before I can `ssh` to the pi.

The time is spent with DHCPDISCOVER actions on eth0 which have to fail. Is there any chance to either change order (wlan0 before eth0) or make this a parallel process in order to speedup system start?

Comment: This would depend on your network, you probably could just set up for a static IP so It doesn't need to query the network as much (apparently you may have to use [these instructions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip) with new Raspbian images, using `/etc/network/interfaces` may still be possible)